# legality of div tag immediately under html tag

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, web-standards

I was running `lynx` to test some HTML I had to do, because having accessibility in mind. I guessed that, if looked pretty in Lynx, the whole range of screen readers, crappy phones and other stuff would do OK, even most ancient hardware.

In some cases I was using a shortcut in case I wanted to wipe out all static HTML at a once for the regular case of when JS is supported and enabled, consisting in nesting all the static HTML tags in an identified `div` tag to be wiped out.

Later I realized that caused a behavior change in my `lynx` compilation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width">
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="whatever">
      <header>
        <h1>First heading</h1>
      </header>
      <main>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
          eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        </p>
      </main>
      <footer>
        <hr />
        <p>
          Footer.
        </p>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Browsing that (in http://driedleav.es/so_20170729/with_div_inside.html too) moves the first header to full left:

[image]

Browsing this other, in http://driedleav.es/so_20170729/without_div_inside.html too, centers the first header:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width">
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>First heading</h1>
    </header>
    <main>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
        eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      </p>
    </main>
    <footer>
      <hr />
      <p>
        Footer.
      </p>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Am unable to catch any difference in behavior when displaying it in the WebKit software of my local host.

**Should I give up the `div` tag used immediately under the `body` tag for the sake of standard, compatibility, and accesibility; at the cost of larger to develop, and larger to download, JS code?**

**Is my Lynx compilation buggy?**

**Are my WebKit compilations buggy?**

Comment: Please check [https://stackoverflow.com/q/45390048/1737973](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45390048/1737973) out too.

Comment: It would probably be much easier for people trying to help you if you included the relevant parts of your code in your  post.

Answer (score 1):

By inserting a `div`, lynx considers the creation of an implicit section which makes the `h1` the title of the section, and no longer the title of the webpage.

You should note that replacing the `<div id="whatever">` with `<main id="whatever">` gives the expected result.