# minimal JS sources for wiping out the whole DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

*This originally came as a spin off from [https://stackoverflow.com/q/45390025/1737973.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45390025/1737973._)*

Sometimes, when JS is supported and enabled in the browser, I find it more useful to rebuild most the DOM (notably under the `body` tag) from scratch, rather than style and give life and RIA to it.

**Which are the vanilla JS sources for wiping out all DOM under the `body` tag in a concise, short yet efficient way?**

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. Also note that questions must be self-contained. (Consider: What if that question is deleted, and this one isn't?) Please formulate a full question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.body.innerHTML = ""
document.head.innerHTML=""
```

...but why?

Comment: That doesn't wipe out the *whole* DOM (if that's what the OP wants to do). Only the parts in `body`. All of the content of `head` remains. Indiscriminately wiping out *all* of the content in `head` is almost certainly a really bad idea, though, and we don't really know what the OP wants to do anyway...

Comment: Am sorry to not asking correctly, I only wanted to remove the DOM element set under the `body` tag.